# VBA Hyperlinks don't work when document is saved as a PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, hyperlink, adobe

My spreadsheet has many tabs which I need to convert to one PDF file along with an index page including hyperlinks to the other pages.  I have code to make links which work within Excel or when I save the PDF manually, but not when I do it through the code.

```
        For Each s In Sheets
            If s.Name Like printNames Then
                s.Select False
            End If
        Next s

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        path & filename & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

where the links are made like:

```
TOCTab.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=anchRange, Address:="", _
SubAddress:="'" & s.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=linkText
```

Any idea what I could do to get this to work in the PDF export?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because VBA itself cannot work in a pdf file. VBA is a Microsoft proprietary programming language that only works in some Microsoft products like Office, and the pdf format is not from Microsoft and does not support VBA.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a work-around?  I don't understand why doing the exact same thing manually and through VBA has different results.

Comment: What do you mean by manually? Do you mean a real link on the Excel sheet? If so, then of course that will work. When you convert your Excel file to pdf, it converts the file without the VBA. Disable your VBA code and you will see the sheet exactly as it will be converted.